# What version of Mac Mini supports Leopard 10.5.8?

Tags: mac-mini

Does Leopard 10.5.8 support the first-ever Mac Mini (M9686*/A, M9687*/A, I think)?

Or do I need one of the later ones?

I'm buying my first-ever mac this Christmas.

Comment: If you are going to get your first-ever Mac, do your best to get an Intel Mac (Mac Mini or whatever), If you get a Power PC, you may find yourself limited, and it will slowly get worse with time, since Apple no longer uses PowerPC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Leopard supports all Intel and all PowerPC based machines over a minimum CPU speed and the original Power PC minus are in that ranges. [Apple doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP517)

Snow Leopard (10.6) only supports Intel based machines