# OS X 10.5 on macmini3,1 model?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, leopard

To reproduce/debug an issue exclusive to OS X 10.5, i was trying install Leopard on my Mac Mini (model "macmini3,1", came with Snow Leopard).
However, when trying to boot from a Leopard install medium (tried both from DVD and USB stick) the machine just hangs:

- when manually choosing the boot medium: hangs with the boot medium selection screen still displayed
- when running the install app from Snow Leopard and letting it restart the machine: hangs with the bright grayish screen and no logo or progress indicator

Does anyone happen to know what could cause this / how to work around it?

Or could my models hardware be too new for 10.5? Although a web search suggests there were/are macmini3,1s with 10.5 running. Also, [this question and it's resource](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4400/what-version-of-mac-mini-supports-leopard-10-5-8?rq=1) suggest it should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual Apple way is that a set of generic OSX disks only support all machines that come out before that OS (How would any know what a new machine might have changed). Machines released after an OS release will include boot disks that can be loaded by that machine but earlier versions might not.

Thus I suspect that your mini is unsupported for Leopard or people bought it earlier with a leopard version for that machine.

Comment: Sadly it looks like this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to boot from a **Power PC** version of the System on an **Intel** processor computer.

Comment: Hm, how could i check that it is? I thought they had both PPC & Intel on the same disc? Both images i have access to exhibit the same behaviour - an unspecified retail image and the one from the developer center (only one version available there, no notes on Intel/PPC).

Comment: If I recall correctly, mounting the DVD / USB on the Desktop should give you some sort of information regarding that.

Comment: The install app works fine on the machine (until the hang after restart) and the Installation readme says "Intel process or Power PC G4" required.

Comment: That gives no clue, I'm afraid. As the *readme* is talking about the 10.5, not that copy. I'm pretty sure this is the problem, as it happened to me once. I'll try to prove me right.